# Java Search an arraylist of strings for words that are in another arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist

As the title says, I have an arraylist of over 10000 words and I wish to use another arraylist of words where I chose the words to search for.  Cant explain it more simple than that but there's the code you may catch on to what I am trying to achieve.  Basically, one arraylist of a lot of words then another arraylist of 5 or so words that will check if those words appear in the long arraylist of words.

```
//TO DO: Profile the search method

    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("textFile.txt"));
        int reps = 100;


        List<String> list = new ArrayList();

         List<String> searchValues = new ArrayList();
         searchValues.add("You");
         searchValues.add("and");
         searchValues.add("So");
         searchValues.add("we");
         searchValues.add("important");

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            list.add(input.next());
        }
        input.close();

        System.out.println("Amount of words in a .txt file: " + list.size());


        //Start to time the method
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                //List value = index.search(list.get(j));
                List value = index.search(list.get(j));


            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time Taken: " + (end - start) + "ms");


    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("File does not exist");
        exc.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Will take a look now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.retainAll(searchValues)
```

will remove all of the values from `list` which are not in `searchValues`. ([Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)))

Answer (score 1):

retainAll internally calls contains() which will iterate over the second list, so you get O(n x m) time complexity searching.

You could search for words by using a hashmap, inserting all entries and finding the ones which occured more than once. This should give you 2 x O(n) + O(m).

However, that would likely not matter if your second list only has 5 objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
list.stream().filter(s -> ! searchValues.contains(s));
```

This will return a stream consisting of the elements that don't exist in the `searchValues` list (considering that you are working with Java 8).